# WPF C# RadioButton visibility not working from class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, boolean

I am binding a RadioButton visibility using BoolToVisConverter.

I put this in xaml file:

```
xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:ScreenS.ViewModel" 

<Window.DataContext>
    <VM:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter" />
</Window.Resources>  

<RadioButton x:Name="SCB0" Visibility="{Binding ShowSCB0, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, FallbackValue=Hidden}" />
```

In the MainViewModel file, I enter:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ScreenS.ViewModel
{
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _scb0;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool ShowSCB0
    {
        get { return _scb0; }
        set
        {
            _scb0 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ShowSCB0");
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in the MainWindow file, I set:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }

    MainViewModel mainView => DataContext as MainViewModel;

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainView.ShowSCB0 = true;
    }
```

Up to here, all works very well.
Problem is when I try to change this value from another class. 
I am using:

```
class abc
{
    MainViewModel viewModel = new MainViewModel(); 

public void someFunction()
    {   
         viewModel.ShowSCB0 = true;
    }
```

This does not set the visibility..

I am getting a bit lost, where am i going wrong?

Comment: "where am i going wrong" - you have 3 different instances of MainViewModel: `<VM:MainViewModel />`, `DataContext = new MainViewModel();`, `MainViewModel viewModel = new MainViewModel();`. you need to work with one

Comment: Somewhat helpful, could you give a little more details by a chance?

Comment: Why is class abc totally disconnected from mainwindowviewmodel? If it's actually a model class it'd be more usual to instantiate it or resolve an instance in mainwindowviewmodel. Resolve as in use a dependency injection container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pay attention the way you instantiate your view models, especially when they are *shared*. Right now all depending types use their own instance of `MainViewModel` (or different references). That's why modifying the value of one instance is not reflected on the other instance.

Make use of `ResourceDictionary`. Consider to make the `MainViewModel` globally accessible by creating a shared instance inside App.xaml resources.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application ... >
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

      <VM:MainViewModel x:Key="SharedMainViewModel" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.DataContext>
  <StaticResource ResourceKey="SharedMainViewModel" />
</Window.DataContext>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs** **(fixed constructor)**

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();   
  // The DataContext is initialized via XAML   
}
```

**Abc.cs**

```
class Abc
{
  private MainViewModel mainViewModel; 

  public Abc()
  {
    this.mainViewModel = Application.Current.Resources["SharedMainViewModel"] as MainViewModel;
  }
}
```